# get parent instance during runtime

Tags: java

I'm trying to get `objects` from `user1` when `toString()` is run from within `user2` but when I use `super` it refers to `Object` instead of `user1`. I think I may have to use reflection but I'm not sure. How can I get `super.objects.get(0)` for `user1` when in its child, `user2`?

```
public abstract class Foo {

    public List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String string) {
       objects.add(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //This line is broken: 
        Object object = super.objects.get(0);
    }

}
```

>

```
public class User extends Foo {}
```

>

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    User user1 = new User();
    User user2 = new User();
    user1.add(user2);
    user2.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `objects` field is `public` (bad practice!), `protected` or package-protected (no explicit access modifier), your child classes will be able to access it directly (if within the same package for the last case).

A `super` invocation from `Foo` will return an instance of `Object` because `Foo` doesn't explicitly extend any class, hence it extends `Object`.

You only need to implement your `toString()` override as `return String.valueOf(objects)` or `String.valueOf(objects.get(myIndex))` - check for empty/`null` in the second case.

The method will be dynamically resolved at runtime and can be invoked from `User` instances, thus representing `objects` or whichever object indexed.

Here's a simple self-contained example, that prints out the whole collection:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Bar());
    }
    static class Foo {
        // package-protected field. A Bar instance will have access here.
        List<Object> objects;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // printing representation of "objects" and avoiding NPE
            return String.valueOf(objects);
        }
    }
    static class Bar extends Foo {
        // overriding default constructor and initializing/populating "objects"
        Bar() {
            objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
            objects.add(1);
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out `[1]`.

**Side-note**

Also, a method returning `String` should actually return `String`. 
Which your `toString` override does not.

Answer (score 0):

The line is working correctly, as `Foo` does not have a superclass declared and as such implicitly subclasses `Object`

If you want to use the `objects` stored in `Foo` you can simply access it as `Object object = objects.get(0);`

Comment: `objects.get(0);` gets `this` `object`. I'm trying to get `super`'s `object`

Comment: There is no `super's object`, as you are trying to retrieve it within `Foo`, which, as mentioned has `Object` as a superclass. The point where you may want to use `super` would be within `User`, but as `objects` is `public` you wouldn't even need it there.